# How to ignore temporarily generated files in SourceTree

Tags: visual-studio, github, sourcetree

Unfortunately, when I was installing SourceTree I didn't click "Install a default global ignore file" and now I am going through hell. I have all those files showing:
 [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qErzo.png)

I found the .gitignore file but I don't know what else should I add. I am a total beginner and I guess I just need the basic .cs file and the solution files to show up. I couldn't find how to ignore the temporarily generated files.
My gitignore file contains:
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr

I tried reinstalling OpenSource but the option to install global ignore file didn't show this time. What should I add to the gitignore file, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `*TemporaryGeneratedFile*` to your .gitignore

Comment: Thank you! I saw similar options but somehow missed this one. It seems i can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation, but I marked your answer green!